# VSCode Theme wont publish to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Im trying to publish a VSCode theme to Azure. When I use the command:

```
vsce package
```

I get the error:

```
WARNING  A 'repository' field is missing from the 'package.json' manifest file.
Do you want to continue? [y/N] y
 WARNING  LICENSE.md, LICENSE.txt or LICENSE not found
Do you want to continue? [y/N] y.
```

However, I have a repository field in my package.json file, I also have a License.md file.
When I attempt to use the command:

```
vsce publish
```

I get the errors mentioned above, as well as:

```
WARNING  A 'repository' field is missing from the 'package.json' manifest file.
Do you want to continue? [y/N] y
 WARNING  LICENSE.md, LICENSE.txt or LICENSE not found
Do you want to continue? [y/N] y
 ERROR  Missing publisher name. Learn more: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#publishing-extensions.
```

However, I have a publisher name in my package.json file. I seem to be getting errors for requirement I have already met?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was due to me not having a publisher name on azure. Make sure to create a publisher name on https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/. As for the errors regarding liscence.md and repository field, I used VSCodes built-in terminal instead of my local one. The errors were resolved. The file directory path was correct, not sure why my local terminal didnt work properly. Ill leave this post up incase anyone has this problem in the future.